# String manipulation in Erlang

Tags: string, erlang

I have a string like this:

```
"productName=\"NAME\"\n"
```

I want to change it to this:

```
"productName=NAME"
```

What is the best way to do this in Erlang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of probably many ways:

```
A = "productName=\"NAME\"\n".
re:replace(A, ["[\"\n]*"], "", [global, {return, list}]).
```

Answer (score 5):

I like also this one, easy to read, very close to Ning proposition:

```
1> A="productName=\"NAME\"\n".
"productName=\"NAME\"\n"
2> lists:filter(fun ($\") -> false; ($\n) -> false; (_) -> true end,A).
"productName=NAME"
```

Answer (score 2):

(Another) one of probably many ways:

```
S0 = "productName=\"NAME\"\n".
[Char || Char <- S0, not lists:member(Char, [$\", $\n])].
```

Comment: It's better to omit `lists:member/2` here: `[Char || Char <- S0, Char =/= $" andalso Char =/= $\n]`

Comment: I'm not sure if it is better since `lists:member/2` is BIF.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant, for example if you want to do this just for that particular key but leave all others alone:

```
A = "productName=\"NAME\"\n".
case A of
    "productName=" ++ S ->
        "productName=" ++ string:strip(S, both, $");
    _ ->
        A
end.
```